# sse inline assembly with g++

Tags: c++, c, g++, inline-assembly, sse

I'm trying out g++ inline assembly and sse and wrote a first program. It segfaults - why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

float s[128*4] __attribute__((aligned(16)));

#define r0 3
#define r1 17
#define r2 110
#define rs0 "3"
#define rs1 "17"
#define rs2 "110"

int main () {
  s[r0*4+0] = 2.0;  s[r0*4+1] = 3.0;  s[r0*4+2] = 4.0;  s[r0*4+3] = 5.0;
  s[r1*4+0] = 3.5;  s[r1*4+1] = 3.5;  s[r1*4+2] = 3.5;  s[r1*4+3] = 3.5;
  asm (
    "\n\t  .intel_syntax noprefix"

    "\n\t  mov     edx,                s"
    "\n\t  movaps  xmm0,               [edx + " rs0 "*16]"
    "\n\t  movaps  xmm1,               [edx + " rs1 "*16]"
    "\n\t  mulps   xmm0,               xmm1"
    "\n\t  movaps  [edx + " rs2 "*16], xmm0"

    "\n\t  .att_syntax"
  );
  printf ("%f %f %f %f\n", s[r2*4+0], s[r2*4+1], s[r2*4+2], s[r2*4+3]);
}
```

And why doesn't gdb allow me to single-step the assembly instructions? Do I need to write asm ("..") around every line?

Comment: [edx + " rs2 "*16] = [edx + 110*16] - isn't this too much? (Just guess).

Comment: Great question, we need more assembly on here.

Comment: IIRC GDB doesn't set up symbols for inline functions (ASM or otherwise). Don't quote me on that, though.

Comment: Use `stepi` to go instruction-by-instruction.

Comment: Yes, I think that this will overflow, but the compiler didn't complain, so I decided to wait and see if it works and then take a look at the disassembly. The segfault occurs also when I replace r0,r1,r2 with 3,4,5.

Comment: `stepi` doesn't show me the assembly instructions.

Comment: `display/ni $pc` will display the next `n` instructions to be executed (all of this is in the GDB manual, by the way; you should really read it).

Comment: Thank you. This allowed me to find out that the program crashes at the first `movaps`: `mov 0x8049170,%edx`, `movaps 0x30(%edx),%xmm0` -> `SIGSEGV`. But why? The alignment seems to be ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're loading the data at `s[0]` into `%edx` and using it as a pointer.  When you then try to access `%edx + 0x30`, you crash, because `s[0] + 48` is not mapped for your process to read from.  (Specifically, since `s` is global and therefore initialized to all zeros, you're trying to load from the address `0x30`)

Comment: Oh. I wanted `mov edx, s` to load the address as an immediate. I'll try to find out the correct instruction or syntax...

Comment: You probably want to be a bit careful about s.  It's a global symbol and might be subject to relocation at link/load time.  Having said that, I've never bothered with inline assembler, sio I might be talking rubbish.

Comment: The correct syntax is: `offset s` - and now it works. Thanks!

Comment: Oh, it doesn't: It prints: `7.000000 10.500000 14.000000 0.000000` ... Where is the last value?

Comment: Solution: `float` -> `volatile float`

Comment: @Thomas: You should be using [input/output directives / clobber lists](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.2) rather than declaring the array `volatile`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `stepi` or `si` to step single machine instructions. Many other functions are available like this with the `-i` suffix, such as `nexti`.

Comment: That's what I tried, but I can't see the assembly instructions in gdb while stepping. It only prints out the final closing ')' bracket of the asm-block.